# How to code typeahead? what are the plugins for it?

Tags: javascript

I've not done typeahead before. Is there any plugins required to perform typeahead in a text field from the datas optained through an ajax request. Any help is appreciated.Thanks

Comment: if you are using jQuery, you can use jQuery Autocomplete: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. But can I get the 'jsonData' array as a response from the ajaxcall

Answer (score 0):

This one is the best [typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) plugin.

```js
var jsonData = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Amazing Moore"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Michele Nata"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Rich Boob"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Tom Nata"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Test Jerry"
  }
]

var productNames = new Array();
var productIds = new Object();
$.each(jsonData, function(index, product) {
  productNames.push(product.name);
  productIds[product.name] = product.id;
});
$('#product').typeahead({
  source: productNames
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://rawgit.com/zeMirco/typeahead.js/master/dist/typeahead.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
<input id='product'></input>
```